# iphone - Crash logs not symbolicated Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, crash-log

Xcode 4.2 doesnt symbolicate my crash logs, these crash logs are generated by my iPhone, not by users iPhone. Im still developing the app and I didnt upload it to the App Store.
I followed some instrucctions on how to manually symbolicate the crash log but I can't find the *.app.dSYM.

When is this generated? Is it generated everytime I execute the app in my Phone?

Sorry if this is a newbie question, but I can't seem to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dwarfdump tool. It is very nice for manual symbolication. you can find your dysm file in derived data folder.

Comment: Can you provide the path? I search in my mac and I can only find 2 files but they were las modified in December.

Comment: /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YourAPP-bvcmvfgtbbkqdqheejkbsrlbxabv/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/

Comment: I am not sure if it will suit you.

Comment: This will only be generated if I previously have archive it, right?
Building and running in my own device won't generate the dSym?